# LearnPythonTheHardWay Exercise 50

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is obviously a simple issue but I just cant seem to get it. In [LPTHW Exercise 50](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html) I am asked to create a webpage foo.html. I have done this and saved it in the templates folder of my projects skeleton.

When I type in `http://localhost:8080` into the browser it automatically locates the index.html page as it should. The file path for this is `Python/projects/gothonweb/templates/index.html`

However when I try to locate my foo.html page by typing in any of the below I am not able to locate it. Its file path is `Python/projects/gothonweb/templates/foo.html`

```
http://localhost:8080/foo.html
http://localhost:8080/templates/foo.html
http://localhost:8080/gothonweb/templates/foo.html
http://localhost:8080/projects/gothonweb/templates/foo.html
http://localhost:8080/Python/projects/gothonweb/templates/foo.html
```

This is my first time useing python on the web, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please post error messages you're getting.

Comment: localhost:8080 isn't an index into a directory onto your computer, it's a server you're running. If you just want to open an html page with your browser you should do the following file:///Python/projects/gothonweb/templates/foo.html. Assuming that that's an absolute path, but it doesn't quite look like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building a web service here, not a static website. Your `.html` files are templates that are used to build dynamic pages, not static pages to serve up. So, it would be bad if `web.py` let you access that `foo.html` automatically.

If you look at the log output, it isn't actually handling a `GET` for `/index.html`, it's handling a `GET` to `/` by using `templates/index.html`.

At any rate, what it *does* serve up is entirely driven by the code you write in `app.py`, and you've told it what to serve here:

```
urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)
```

What this says is that requests for `/` should be handled by an instance of the `index` class. That class looks like this:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/')

class index:
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Hello World"
        return render.index(greeting=greeting)
```

In other words, it doesn't "automatically locate the index.html page as it should", it automatically locates the `index` class, which uses a renderer which is explicitly pointed at `index.html` (via the `render.index` bit).

The exercise explicitly explains all of this, and then asks you to:

> Also create another template named templates/foo.html and render that using render.foo() instead of render.index() like before.

So, that's what you have to do. You have to render it using `render.foo()`.

The simplest way is to do this:

```
urls = (
  '/', 'index',
  '/foo', 'foo'
)

# ...

class foo:
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Foo"
        return render.foo(greeting=greeting)
```

There are more flexible ways to do things, but you'll learn them as you go through a web.py tutorial. (Which the exercise also asked you to do before continuing on.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a route to your `foo.html` file.  From the LPTHW Exercise 50, Here is the relevant code in your `bin/app.py`:

```
import web

urls = (
  '/', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Hello World"
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Notice a couple things:

1. The `urls` variable, your routes, only has a route to the `/` path.
2. In the `Index` class you are calling `render.index`

So, one thing you could do, as it suggests right before the **Study Drills** section of the exercise, is to simply change the `render.index` call to `render.foo`.  With the web framework being used, this will render the `foo.html` file when you load the index path.

Another thing you could do is add another route to your `urls` and create a `class Foo` to catch this route:

```
import web

urls = (
  '/', 'Index',
  '/foo', 'Foo'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "Hello World"
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

class Foo(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now when you go to `http://localhost:8080/foo` it will render your `foo.html` template.

Comment: Thanks mVChr, an excellent answer. I was already following @abarnert answer which solved it first. But thanks, perfect example